# Select distinct in Linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2010

I've a collection with the data like this.

```
-------------------------------------------- 
|  key   | customer Name | code | isActive | 
--------------------------------------------
| 30002  |    XYZ        | 234  |     1    |
--------------------------------------------
| 30002  |    XYZ        | 234  |     1    |
--------------------------------------------
| 30002  |    XYZ        | 234  |     1    |
--------------------------------------------
| 30034  |    ERR        | 344  |     1    |
--------------------------------------------
| 30031  |    LDD        | 343  |     1    |
--------------------------------------------
```

how can select the distinct data using linq?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own comparier like this:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
    {
        public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y) {
            return x["col1"] == y.["col1"] && x["col2"] == y.["col2"];
        }

        public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj) {
            return obj["col1"].GetHashCode() ^ obj["col2"].GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Then use:

```
var distinctRows = (from dr in table.AsEnumerable()
select dr).Distinct(new MyComparer());
```

I think that code can be optimized, but the overall idea is presented :)

Answer (score 6):

captain obvious said that you should use `Distinct` linq method :-)

Comment: Exact, but don´t forget to overide the Equals method on the RowObject. If you are using tablerows or something you can give a EqualityComparer to the IEnumerable.Distinct() method.

Comment: can you give me an example for this query?

Comment: @nagg How can i use that distinct keyword in linq?

Comment: @ArooranS, simply, let's say we have array of Foo - fooArray, so it will be: var distinctedArray = fooArray.Distinct().ToArray(); //don't forget to add "using System.Linq". PS: important note - read Glenn comment above.

Comment: @Nagg thanks for your reply. i have a customer collection class that has all data like this. i tried that code like this Dim TC = tCustomers.Distinct() but it doesn't worked